# ¿Existe el antónimo de "escrupuloso" cuando se refiere a asco hacia los alimentos?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, antónimos

Según el DRAE:

> [**escrupuloso, sa**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GLBc03N)
>
> Del lat. *scrupulōsus*.
>
> 1. adj. Que padece o tiene escrúpulos. Apl. a pers., u. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. Dicho de una cosa: Que causa escrúpulos.

Y por su parte:

> **[escrúpulo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GKtF7vE)**
>
> Del lat. *scrupŭlus* 'piedrecilla'.
>
> 2. m. Aprensión, asco hacia algo, especialmente hacia algún alimento.

Existen otras acepciones, pero esta es la que me interesa. Se suele usar cuando una persona siente asco hacia algún alimento, por el motivo que sea (por ejemplo, que otra persona lo haya chupado o tocado previamente).

¿Existe el antónimo de este caso? Es decir, alguna palabra para definir al que no siente asco por ningún alimento (o como he oído decir, al que come cosas que harían vomitar a una cabra).

Comment: según wordreference los antónimos de escrúpulos son **decidía y negligencia**. http://www.wordreference.com/sinonimos/escr%C3%BApulo y según la RAE está **inescrupuloso** http://dle.rae.es/?id=LT6Zqt6

Comment: A los que comen cualquier cosa, en Chile les decimos **chancho**, es decir "puerco".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la RAE encontramos **inescrupuloso** http://dle.rae.es/?id=LT6Zqt6

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona: Que carece de escrúpulos.
> 2. adj. Dicho o hecho sin escrúpulos.

lo que por definición es el antónimo de **escrupuloso** en todos los sentidos.

Comment: De hecho recuerdo haber leído en distintos lugares de la Colombia rural: _Cuidado, no haga caso a ofertas de venta de esta parcela. Personas inescrupulosas podrían engañarlo_.

Comment: @fedorqui correcto y eso tiene que ver con las definiciones 1 y 3 de "escrupulo" http://dle.rae.es/?id=GKtF7vE Sobre lo de la comida es la acepción 2

Comment: Y fíjate qué curiosa la etimología: _Del lat. scrupŭlus 'piedrecilla'_. Los escrúpulos no dejan de ser piedrecillas que nos molestan en el zapato de la moral :)

Answer (score 2):

No hay un antónimo directo, ni siquiera restringiendo el uso del termino para la comida, porque dependiendo del contexto hay un rango amplio de significados para lo que quieres expresar, y es uso es muy subjetivo.

Alguien que no tiene reparos o remilgos en comerse algo, puede ser simplemente `despreocupado`, `descuidado` o llegar a `negligente`. O quizá sea solo un `inconsciente`.

Cuantos dias despues de la fecha de caducidad te puedes comer un yogur (a sabiendas de que lo haces)? Si es uno o dos dias despues yo diría (y es una aplicación completamente subjetiva del termino) que alguien es `despreocupado`. Estoy seguro de que no pasa nada. Mi mujer en cambio nunca haría lo mismo (vamos, ya duda si es el mismo día de la fecha...) y para ella tal persona seria seguramente `descuidada` o `inconsciente` de lo que le puede llegar a pasar. Si pasa una semana de la fecha alguien ya esta siendo un poco `negligente`.

Hay gente que no quiere comer cierto tipo de comida solo por el sabor o la textura, o incluso la procedencia. Por ejemplo, con unos callos madrileños. Para algunos sera el saber de donde vienen, mientras que para otros será el sabor o la textura la razón por la que no lo quieran comer.

Y como este espectro se puede dar para muchas cosas y es tan subjetivo, como quitarle lo pocho y comerte el resto de la fruta, el sabor de la comida aunque no este mala (por caduca) y similar, es muy difícil encontrar un antónimo directo para "escrupuloso con la comida".

Es mas frecuente ver un:

> No tiene remilgos/reparos en comerse XYZ

o similar, ya sea por el sabor, la apariencia, la calidad, o la salubridad.

Answer (score 1):

Estás buscando más bien una palabra que permita definir a una suerte de troglodita voraz capaz de comer cualquier cosa... Lo veo difícil y no se me ocurren otras palabras que las siguientes: voraz, tragón, glotón, comilón.

Pero si fuera específicamente por lo de un antónimo de escrupuloso, diría alguna de estas: indiferente, descuidado, despreocupado, inconsciente, imprudente... aunque no tienen estricta relación con las prácticas alimenticias.